# python: What's the rationale behind not allowing * in relative imports?

Tags: python, relative-path, python-packaging

What's the rationale behind not allowing * in relative imports? e.g.

```
from ..new_tool import *
```

or doing a relative import directly:

```
import ..new_tool
```

Comment: from ..new_tool import * is not healthy.. It will import every thing under ..new_tool. It may create a conflict with your method_name or attribute_name if your declared name matches with the imported name. Some time cyclic dependencies may occur ..

Comment: @Tauquir: that applies to any `import *`, not just relative ones specifically.

Comment: still waiting for an answer on the `import *` part that doesn't also apply to the regular one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the latter is prohibited is that `..new_tool` is not usable in an expression [(PEP 328)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/):

> The reason `import .foo` is prohibited
>   is because after
>
> ```
>     import XXX.YYY.ZZZ
> ```
>
> then `XXX.YYY.ZZZ` is usable in an
>   expression. But
>
> ```
>     .moduleY
> ```
>
> is not usable in an
>   expression.

Since `*`-imports should only ever be a quick hack while in development, I suspect the functionality for relative `*`-imports was left out because it's not necessary.

Comment: hmm i suppose they could have done `import .foo as _foo`. it is nice not having `import *`s in your code though.

Comment: Be weird to allow `import ... as` but not a bare `import` though.

Comment: true. actually i guess you can always do `from . import foo`, so you dont lose anything by not being able to do `import .foo`.